# symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff not creating version file

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I already did some migrations with symfony 1.4, but for some reason, it's no longer working.

I have my OLD model, and i added a brand new table to my schema.yml.

When I write `symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-diff` i have the following ouput.

```
>> doctrine  generating migration diff
>> file+     C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\...\Temp/doctrine_schema_57991.yml
>> doctrine  Generated migration classes successfully from difference
```

Okay, that's great i have a copy of my schema.yml in my users temp file, but what i want is the version file to do the `symfony doctrine:migrate` so my database will be changed according to the schema.

Can someone help me doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting my old version files solved the problem